# PDF.js - Password Callback Issue When Wrong Password is Entered

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, mozilla, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js for my project and I am facing issue with encrypted pdf's. I am using PDF.js passwordCallback function to provide the password.

```
PDFJS.getDocument(file, null, passwordCB, null).then(function (res) {
console.log("Document Decrypted);
});
```

Here is the passwordCallback Function

```
var passwordCB = function (passwordFunc, reason) {
  if (reason === 1) {
    passwordFunc(pdfpassword);
  } else {
    console.log("Wrong Password");
  }
};
```

When a wrong password is provided, the control do not get out of passwordCB function. It get's stuck until a valid password is provided.

So when user enters a wrong password I have to tell them that the password is wrong and need to get a new password. I am not using the default javascript prompt.

Is there a way to break the passwordCallback function and return to the getDocument() promise?

Also, from the source code it is mentioned that the passwordCallback is deprecated.

```
* @param {function} passwordCallback (deprecated) It is used to request a
* password if wrong or no password was provided. The callback receives two
* parameters: function that needs to be called with new password and reason
* (see {PasswordResponses}).
```

Is there any other way to provide password for the document? Any article or example on this scenario?

Comment: Crosspost at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7806 -- answered there.

Comment: That is little confusing. Do you have any examples on handling wrong passwords for PDF using passwordCallback or onPassword callback?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, for you:

```
function loadDocumentUsingPassword(){
    PDFJS.getDocument(file, null, passwordCB, null).then(function (res) {
        console.log("Document Decrypted");
    });

function passwordCB (passwordFunc, reason) {
  if (reason === 1) { // need a password
    var new_password= confirm('Please enter a password:')
  } else { // Invalid password
    var new_password= confirm('Invalid! Please enter a password:')
  }
  passwordFunc(new_password);
};
```

The user is asked to enter a password. until he enter

Comment: This goes into my angular service. I cannot use confirm or any native javascript thing. I need to break this promise and call this again with a new password. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need to break. You can use angular code here. Please upload a JSFiddle with you code, and we try to help

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/LNACGO5OFmasiUH3L896?p=preview Let me know if you want more details on the code

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/7f6a607ea537a6237802fe11e211afb2b19af9cf/web/app.js#L649 :

```
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(parameters);
loadingTask.onPassword = function passwordNeeded(updateCallback, reason) {
  savedUpdateCallback = updateCallback;
  // show reason to user
};
```

and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/7f6a607ea537a6237802fe11e211afb2b19af9cf/web/password_prompt.js#L106:

```
// collect newPassword
savedUpdateCallback(newPassword);
```

No need to cancel loadingTask -- it will wait until saved `updateCallback` is called.

Comment: Thank you. Can you take a look at the comment here and let me know how I can achieve that? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7806

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below url that will prompt for password, until the correct password is given. The password for the pdf is "test".

http://learnnewhere.unaux.com/pdfViewer/passwordviewer.html

Here is the sample code for prompting password

```
    pdfJs.onPassword = function (updatePassword, reason) { 
      if (reason === 1) { // need a password
            var new_password= prompt('Please enter a password:');
            updatePassword(new_password);
        } else { // Invalid password
            var new_password= prompt('Invalid! Please enter a password:');
            updatePassword(new_password);
        }
   };
```

You could get the complete code from here https://github.com/learnnewhere/simpleChatApp/tree/master/pdfViewer