# Unlock and Save PDF file protected by password In NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js

I have some pdf files in a directory, protected by both passwords (I have the password to open files) and I want to open them, on the server side, and save a copy unprotected. Is there a way to do this in NodeJS or pure Javascript? I've tried the PDFjs like below, but always return the same error : "structuredClone is not definied".

Thank you for for any help.

```
 const retorno = await PDFJS.getDocument({ data: someBinaryConvertedPDF, password: 'secret' })
                .promise.
                    then( function(pdf_doc) {

                        console.log(pdf_doc);

                            }).catch(function(error) {
                
                               console.log(error);
              
            });;
```

EDIT: I've triyng with pdfjs package, follow the KJ suggestions in commentaries, unsucessfully again :(

```
const PDFJS = require('pdfjs');

function loadDocumentUsingPassword() {

    PDFJS.getDocument(pathWithFile, null, 'secret', null).then(function (res) {
        console.log("Document Decrypted");
    });

};


loadDocumentUsingPassword();
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english :( .. When i've said "both protected", it means all the pdf files that i've have it are protected by a password. And i have the password, i need to create a new file, a exactly copy, but unprotected, whitout a password... Thanks for the links, i wil check that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i will try qpdf for Node again, i would not like to create dependences in SO for my application works, because of this i've searching for other alternatives than qpdf. By the way, i've tried the function on your link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576914/pdf-js-password-callback-issue-when-wrong-password-is-entered#40577113), but return this error "PDFJS.getDocument is not a function". I'm tried to use the pdfjs package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs).

Comment: Here is the code. The configuration of calling is correctly, at first view:

Comment: const PDFJS = require('pdfjs');

function loadDocumentUsingPassword() {

    PDFJS.getDocument(pathWithFile, null, 'secret', null).then(function (res) {
        console.log("Document Decrypted");
    });

};


loadDocumentUsingPassword();

Comment: I'm not sure if i've understand your aswer, but i don't need a editor or interface for the user input the password. All the process will be running in a backend service. I will be receive the file and the password in a directory, and the service will be ready the files an the password automatically, and send for another API who needs the PDF file unprotected...

Comment: Thank you so much @KJ, for the informations. I will use qpdf, in splite of need to install dependecies in OS's server.